# Probability of getting k or less items at least once in a multinomial draw

Tags: probability

Suppose you have N balls that are randomly allocated to M urns. What is the probability that at least one urn ends up with K or fewer balls?

Example: $N=20, M=4, K=0.$ There are $20$ balls. For each ball, you roll a $4$-sided die and place it into one of $4$ urns depending on the roll. What is the chance that at least one urn will have $0$ balls at the end? Originally I was thinking that, for any one urn, the chance of getting $0$ balls in this example is $(3/4)^{20}$, so the chance that $0$ balls never happens is $(1-(3/4)^{20})^4$. However then I realized that had to be wrong, since the $4$ urns are not independent (if a ball doesn't go into urn $A$, it must go into urn $B, C$, or $D$).

Comment: The case of $K=0$ is routine.  The case of larger $K$ will get more complicated and tedious.  Approach with inclusion-exclusion.  Let $A$ be the event that urn A is empty.  Similarly define events $B,C,D$.  You have $\Pr(A\cup B\cup C\cup D)$ is the event that at least one urn is empty.  It expands via [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) as $\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)+\Pr(C)+\Pr(D)-\Pr(A\cap B)-\Pr(A\cap C)-\dots -\Pr(C\cap D)+\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)+\dots - \Pr(A\cap B\cap C\cap D)$

Comment: There is a far simpler shorthand to writing this involving [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Answer (score 1):

We have $m$ urns, $n$ balls and at least one urn having $k$ or less balls. Of course if $n \lt m (k+1)$, it is certain. So assuming $n \geq m (k+1)$, one of the approaches would be to write a generating function.

We first find all arrangements such that each of the urns has at least $k+1$ balls and then subtract from total number of arrangements, that is $ \displaystyle m^n$. That gives us number of arrangements where at least one of the urns has $k$ or less balls.

Using exponential generating function, the number of arrangements can be written as,

$ \displaystyle n! \cdot \left[x^n \ | \left (\sum_{i = k +1}^{n} \cdot \frac{x^i}{i!} \right)^m \right] \ $

That is to first find the coefficient of $x^n$ in the  series and then multiply by $n!$ to get all the arrangements where there are at least $k+1$ balls in each urn.

Also note that the upper bound of $i$ can be reduced as we know each urn has at least $k+1$ balls so any one urn cannot have more than $n - (m-1) (k+1)$ balls.

Depending on the size of $m, n, k$, you can either use tools like WolframAlpha or write a computer program.